# What does it mean to probe a certain energy scale?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology, large-hadron-collider, electroweak

For example, what does it mean that the LHC probe the electroweak scale, $M_{EW} \sim  10^3 GeV$? Also why is this energy called the electroweak scale?

Comment: [Electroweak scale](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale)

Answer (score 0):

In short, energy scale means kinetic energies given to proton beams which are then smashed  towards each other. The bigger kinetic energies,- more interesting output particles after beams collision can emerge, reassembling universe state/conditions at a greater scale back in time. For example if we could probe Planck scale, which is about $10^{19}~\text{GeV}$ ,- we may potentially re-create first glimpses of our BigBang model and to verify Hawking radiation and existence of micro-black holes. But sadly this will not happen with LHC as it is designed "only" for maximum of $10~\text{TeV}$ kinetic energies.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we express energy as E = hc/(lambda) where lambda is a wavelength. Then the characteristic "energy scale" for visible light spans the range of energies corresponding to the wavelengths of infrared to ultraviolet light.

Note that this equation associates high energies with short wavelengths, which means to study objects that have very short characteristic (wave)lengths requires the use of high energies.

We can theoretically calculate the energy range over which we expect electroweak phenomena to be important and then associate that range or "scale" of energies with a corresponding range of sizes via E = hc/(lambda). This means that to probe the electroweak scale we need something with an extremely short wavelength, like a super-energetic photon or subatomic particle.

Those very energetic probes can be made in very powerful particle accelerators. In this sense, the achievable beam energies that a given accelerator can reach establish the "scale" of objects it can "see".