# Are there different ways of using the term 'energy scale'?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, education

Are there a few different ways of using the term 'energy scale' that differ in their precise meanings? For instance, in the context of the chart provided, 'energy scales' denotes the magnitude of energy required for probing particles in particle accelerators to interact with specific particle types for the purpose of studying their behaviors. Is this correct?

[image]

This appears to be conceptually distinct and possibly even numerically disparate from the energy magnitudes typically exchanged during interactions between particles of varying types as listed in the chart.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/791067/what-does-it-mean-to-probe-a-certain-energy-scale).

Answer (score 1):

In what are called *natural units*, energy has units of 1/length- so small lengths are naturally associated with high energies.

A good explanation of how this works can be found in the opening chapters of Voits' book on string theory called *Not Even Wrong*.